# How to fix starting .jar file without changing a manifest specified main class?

Tags: java

I've written a main class inside a class named Other. Made it a jar file(I think I did it correctly.). 
Used jar cf project.jar bin/.
Haven't altered the manifest file cause I wanted  to do it without doing so.

then used java -cp project.jar com.something.Other 
and i keep getting an error ( on mint ) saying Could not find or load main class projekt.jar

Also after trying to add mymanifest.txt using jar cfm projekt.jar mymanifest.txt -C bin\ i get error parsing file arguments

I've tried replacing everything with . / after the .jar also tried with \ and im not sure what to do.

Just wish to get the program to start without altering the manifest file just to try it out.

edit : if I use jar cf projekt2.jar -C bin\ it gives ">" and an Error parsing file arguments to create an archived file.
but using jar cf projekt2. jar /bin makes it work.

If i use

```
java-cp projekt2.jar /hr.fer.zemris.java.tecaj_1.Glavni
```

or

```
 java-cp projekt2.jar \hr.fer.zemris.java.tecaj_1.Glavni
```

or

```
java-cp projekt2.jar hr.fer.zemris.java.tecaj_1.Glavni
```

it all gives similar error message saying Could not find or load main class hr.fer.zemris.java.tecaj_1.Glavni while first one adds . before the hr
Caused by : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : hr.fer.zemris.java.tecaj_1.Glavni

edit2:

```
package hr.fer.zemris.java.tecaj_1;

/**
 *  program koji ilustrira razdvajanje koda u više razreda.
 *
 *  @author
 *  @version 1.0
 */

public class Glavni{
    /**
     *  Metoda od koje kreće izvođenje programa.
     *  @param args argumenti komandne linije. Ne koristimo ih.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Pozdrav ! Učimo javu!");
        System.out.println();
        Formule.ispisiSlucajnuFormulu();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste your terminal contents showing your commands and the results?

Comment: Also post the code of your class `Glavni`...

Comment: its simple hello world kinda thing